# trying to script ntp client settings

Tags: scripts, 22.04, systemd-timesyncd

Im writing or trying to write a script that will add some NTP servers to 22.04 server.

```
Setntpclient()
{
sudo cp /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf.bk_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
echo
sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf #setting to rw for user and group
sudo cat > /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf <<EOF
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the timesyncd.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details
[Time]
NTP=ntp0.domain.com ntp1.domain.com
FallbackNTP=IpAdd1 IpAdd2
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
EOF
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-timedated.service
sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
sudo timedatctl set-timezone "Europe/London"
echo timedatectl status
}
Setntpclient
```

Now when I go to restart the systemd-timesyncd.service I get an error.

```
Permission denied
Failed to restart systemd-timesyncd.service: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked.
```

So I added the "sudo systemctl unmask systemd-timedated.service" to the script.

Now from reading what I am guessing is when you run a shell script it runs it from /tmp and this maybe causing the issue? If so what is the way around this?

---

Update to clarify what I'm seeing

ntp.conf is being updated but when it comes time to restart the timesynd service its fails with the error.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Are you talking about the "permission denied" error? If so, is the script being run as a normal user? Then `sudo cat > file ...` won't work - the redirection is done as that user, not by `sudo`. You need `sudo tee file` instead

Comment: Hi muru, Still learning linux, But this is my logic. changed the file permissions on the ntp.conf to user read-write and group read-write. sudo cat and push that into the ntp.conf. this has worked for what ever reason. but getting permission denied on the restart of the timesyncd service. I gave you the full script so you can see what i was trying to do. Rather than just giving you the error message.

Comment: Are you sure the file contents were updated? None of the other commands are likely to give _that_ "permission denied" error

Comment: Hi muru, rebuild my ubuntu instance and ran the script. yeah you were right getting permission denied on the timesyncd.conf. I have moved to tee thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Appreciated.